# Spring-Data: Generated values effects updating entity instead of insert

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data

There is a behaviour I dont understand.

I have to entities like:

```
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(of={"name"})
@ToString(of={"name", "entityB"})
public class EntityA {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String name;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @ManyToOne(fetch=EAGER, cascade={PERSIST, MERGE})
    private EntityB entityB;

}

@ToString(of = { "name" })
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = { "name" })
@Entity
class EntityB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Long id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @XmlAttribute
    @Column(nullable=false, unique=true)
    private String name;
}
```

And a logic to insert data to db:

```
@Component
public class DatabaseInitializer implements InitializingBean {
    @Autowired EntityARepository repository; // Spring-Data CrudRepository!

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        final Set<EntityA> aEntities = createAEntities();
        repository.save(aEntities);

        Iterator<EntityA> iterator = repository.findAll().iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
    }

    private  Set<EntityA> createAEntities() throws Exception {
        Set<EntityA> aEntities = new HashSet<>();
        aEntities.add(getFirstEntityA());
        aEntities.add(getSecondEntityA());
        return aEntities;
    }

    private EntityA getFirstEntityA(){
        EntityA a = new EntityA();
        a.setId(1L);
        a.setName("a-1");
        a.setEntityB(getFirstEntityB());
        return a;
    }   

    private EntityA getSecondEntityA(){
        EntityA a = new EntityA();
        a.setId(2L);
        a.setName("a-2");
        a.setEntityB(getFirstEntityB());
        return a;
    }

    //

    private EntityB getFirstEntityB() {
        EntityB b = new EntityB();
        b.setId(1l);
        b.setName("b-1");
        return b;
    }

}
```

When starting application, I get following outputs:

```
org.hibernate.SQL: select entitya0_.id as id1_0_1_, entitya0_.entityb_id as entityb_3_0_1_, entitya0_.name as name2_0_1_, entityb1_.id as id1_1_0_, entityb1_.name as name2_1_0_ from entitya entitya0_ left outer join entityb entityb1_ on entitya0_.entityb_id=entityb1_.id where entitya0_.id=?
org.hibernate.SQL: select entityb0_.id as id1_1_0_, entityb0_.name as name2_1_0_ from entityb entityb0_ where entityb0_.id=?
org.hibernate.SQL: insert into entityb (id, name) values (default, ?)
org.hibernate.SQL: insert into entitya (id, entityb_id, name) values (default, ?, ?)
org.hibernate.SQL: update entitya set entityb_id=?, name=? where id=?

EntityA(name=a-1, entityB=EntityB(name=b-1))
```

As you can see, it updates entitya instead of adding a new row to db.

When I remove the `@GeneratedValue` from both entities it works.

```
org.hibernate.SQL: select entitya0_.id as id1_0_1_, entitya0_.entityb_id as entityb_3_0_1_, entitya0_.name as name2_0_1_, entityb1_.id as id1_1_0_, entityb1_.name as name2_1_0_ from entitya entitya0_ left outer join entityb entityb1_ on entitya0_.entityb_id=entityb1_.id where entitya0_.id=?
org.hibernate.SQL: select entityb0_.id as id1_1_0_, entityb0_.name as name2_1_0_ from entityb entityb0_ where entityb0_.id=?
org.hibernate.SQL: select entitya0_.id as id1_0_1_, entitya0_.entityb_id as entityb_3_0_1_, entitya0_.name as name2_0_1_, entityb1_.id as id1_1_0_, entityb1_.name as name2_1_0_ from entitya entitya0_ left outer join entityb entityb1_ on entitya0_.entityb_id=entityb1_.id where entitya0_.id=?
org.hibernate.SQL: insert into entityb (name, id) values (?, ?)
org.hibernate.SQL: insert into entitya (entityb_id, name, id) values (?, ?, ?)
org.hibernate.SQL: insert into entitya (entityb_id, name, id) values (?, ?, ?)

EntityA(name=a-1, entityB=EntityB(name=b-1))
EntityA(name=a-2, entityB=EntityB(name=b-1))
```

When I want to use ID-Generator and remove setId(...) from entity-creator, I get a `NullPointerException` in `HsqlException`.

```
    Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.persist.RowStoreAVL.indexRow(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.TransactionManager2PL.addInsertAction(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.addInsertAction(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.Table.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertRowSet(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    ... 87 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hsqldb.index.IndexAVLMemory.insert(Unknown Source) ~[hsqldb-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    ... 96 common frames omitted
```

At least what I want is that I don`t need to give entityA a identifier, it should generate by it self and I want at least two entitiesA.

Comment: Can you please post the complete stacktrace? That might help. Also which version of hsql are you using?

Comment: Also, can you remove `unique` constaint on `name` field of `entityB` and test along with removing the call to setId(...)? I doubt if it is throwing ConstraintViolated exception for the second insert of entityA insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At least what I want is that I don`t need to give entityA a identifier, it should generate by it self and I want at least two entitiesA.

I believe you don't want to assign the ids manually for entityA and entityB. If so you can remove `a.setId(1L)`, `a.setId(2L)` and `b.setId(1l)` and try.

As you are using `@GeneratedValue` it uses stragegy as `GenerationType.AUTO` and will populate the ids for you.

On a different note, `repository.save(...)` is a dual method and it decides if the entity with the same id already exists or not. If an entity with that id already exists in the database, it issues update statement else it issues insert statement.

In you case, since you are using the same entityB instance that has same id for both entityA instances, I believe it is treating it as an existing entity the update statement is getting issued for the second entityA instead of creating new one.

*****UPDATE*****

I have tried the code by removing the calls to `setId(...)` on both `EntityA` and `EntityB` it resulted in following error, because the `unique=true` is present on the `name` field of `EntityB`.

```
Hibernate: insert into entityb (id, name) values (null, ?)
Hibernate: insert into entitya (id, entityb_id, name) values (null, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into entityb (id, name) values (null, ?)
2016-09-19 18:11:28.960  WARN 10956 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
2016-09-19 18:11:28.960 ERROR 10956 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unique index or primary key violation: "UK_Q9VYNGA314JSWU3TEA1LCF3P4_INDEX_C ON PUBLIC.ENTITYB(NAME) VALUES ('b-1', 1)"; SQL statement:
insert into entityb (id, name) values (null, ?) [23505-190]
2016-09-19 18:11:28.990 ERROR 10956 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["UK_Q9VYNGA314JSWU3TEA1LCF3P4_INDEX_C ON PUBLIC.ENTITYB(NAME) VALUES ('b-1', 1)"; SQL statement:
insert into entityb (id, name) values (null, ?) [23505-190]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unique index or primary key violation: "UK_Q9VYNGA314JSWU3TEA1LCF3P4_INDEX_C ON PUBLIC.ENTITYB(NAME) VALUES ('b-1', 1)"; SQL statement:
insert into entityb (id, name) values (null, ?) [23505-190]
```

After removing that `unique=true`, it resulted in created two `EntityA` instances as expected

```
Hibernate: insert into entityb (id, name) values (null, ?)
Hibernate: insert into entitya (id, entityb_id, name) values (null, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into entityb (id, name) values (null, ?)
Hibernate: insert into entitya (id, entityb_id, name) values (null, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select entitya0_.id as id1_3_, entitya0_.entityb_id as entityb_3_3_, entitya0_.name as name2_3_ from entitya entitya0_
EntityA [id=1, name=a-2, entityB=EntityB [id=1, name=b-1]]
EntityA [id=2, name=a-1, entityB=EntityB [id=2, name=b-1]]
```

So you may want to remove unique constraint on `name` field of `entityB` and test along with removing the call`to`setId(...)` method.

FYI, I have used h2 database for testing.

Comment: Thank you for reply. When I remove the a.setId(1L), then I become NullPointException, see question above.